# Was the review reputation requirement raised?

Tags: discussion, review

I am a rather active reviewer on the main site. But today, when I was looking for new items, I was told I need a reputation of at least 500 to do so.

Is this a bug? If not: Why wasn’t this rather important change announced here? The quality of many questions and answers here is even worse than on WordPress Stack Exchange where I am a moderator, so I think any help should be welcome, not rejected.

Comment: Sounds like a good reason to earn one more up-vote...

Comment: @Shog9 This isn’t about me, I can get that easily. :) But I think this should have been communicated in advance.

Comment: I just asked on Sports beta as well...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes it was:

[Propose a privilege to sit in the 500 reputation mark](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186373/propose-a-privilege-to-sit-in-the-500-reputation-mark)

It was done (primarily for Stack Overflow) where low rep users are automatically approving bad edits in an effort reduce the number of bad edits getting into the system.

It's unfortunate that it will catch some good reviewers who have less than 500 reputation.

If it becomes a problem we can ask about getting it changed on a site-by-site basis (which is possible).

Answer (score 3):

Oh, I just found this: [Propose a privilege to sit in the 500 reputation mark](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186373/propose-a-privilege-to-sit-in-the-500-reputation-mark)

> **Make access to the First Posts and Late Answer Review queues a 500 rep privilege.**
>
> Hopefully this will prevent the blind from leading the blind.
>
> As a possible side benefit it may slow down the badge hunters till they get a better idea of what the review queues are really for and whats expected when doing a review.

On sites with low voting activity, this is rather contra-productive. :/